# Javascript: How to hijack input type=submit on click behavior?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a button:

Whenever I click on it, it submits to a form.

I want to hijack this behavior, so when I click, it calls a JS function instead. How do I do this? I added:

```
$('input.submit').live('click', addFood);
```

The problem is it still submits to the form. When I remove "type="submit", it works.

I don't want to remove the HTML code. it'a also bound to CSS, and I don't want to change CSS because I'm afraid of messing it up =)

So question is: how do to change behavior of submit button so it doesn't submit to form but calls my Javascript (JQuery) function?

Comment: Oops, I just realized I needed a "return false" in my addFoods function, otherwise it calls the function AND submits it to the form. Problem solved! Off to bed =)

Comment: Hisoka: it's ok to answer your own question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Target the form instead, not the submit button

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = false;

    // do things
});
```

Comment: This solution was deprecated in Jquery 1.7

Answer (score 13):

Just for the sake of keeping this answer updated change :

```
$("form").live('submit', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = false;

    // do things
});
```

with :

```
$("form").on('submit', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = false;

    // do things
});
```

`$(selector).live()` was deprecated in Jquery 1.7 and removed from the framework in Jquery 1.9.

Here´s the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/live/)